# removing div from html in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to remove the following div from a page with my chrome extension

**HTML (TO REMOVE)**

```
<div class="base-popup js-base-popup"><div class="js-obscurity base-popup__obscurity"></div>
<div class="base-popup__indent"></div>
<div class="base-popup__wrap">
    <div class="base-popup__container clearfix base-popup__container -decor" style="width:500px;">


                <i class="s-icon -m -close base-popup__close js-close"></i>


        <div class="base-popup__content  js-content"><div><div class="s-text">Sample Text.
    <!-- close tag -->
    </p>
    <!-- close tag in translate  -->
</div></div></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS in my content script

```
 function removeElementsByClassName(names) {
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName(names),
            i, element;
        for (i = els.count - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
            element = els[i];
            element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
        }
    }

removeElementsByClassName('base-popup js-base-popup');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` only accepts a *single* class name, but you're giving it two. Since the HTML you've shown only has a single element that has either of the two classes you're using, if that's the only element you want to remove, just pick one:

```
removeElementsByClassName("base-popup");
// or
removeElementsByClassName("js-base-popup");
```

Alternately, you could use `querySelectorAll` with a CSS selector:

```
function removeElementsBySelector(selector) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
        i, element;
    for (i = els.count - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
        element = els[i];
        element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
    }
}
```

Then if you want to remove elements that have *either* class:

```
removeElementsBySelector('.base-popup, .js-base-popup');
```

Or if you only want to remove a single element that has *both* classes:

```
removeElementsBySelector('.base-popup.js-base-popup');
```

---

And as this is a Chrome extension, you can do that rather more simply with `Array.from`, `forEach`, and `Element#remove`:

```
function removeElementsBySelector(selector) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(element => {
        element.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Neither of these seems to be working for me.I want to remove everything here from the html above.Basically the `<div class="base-popup js-base-popup">` class and anything inside it as well

Comment: @user2650277 did youve awaited the window onload? (window.onload=function(){your code};

Comment: Ahh that was it ...Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

your javascript is completely wrong. the right way:

```
 function removeElementsByClassName(names){
    names=names.split(" ");//you just get elems by one class so you need to split it into multiple operations
    for(var a=1;a<names.length;a++){//ability to remove multiple classes
     removeElementsByClassName(names[a]);
     }
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(names[0]);
    for (var i =0; i<els.length ; i++) { // its length not count
        var element = els[i];
        element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
    }
 }

removeElementsByClassName('base-popup js-base-popup');
```

this removes all elements that contain one of these classes, if you wanted sth else see the other solution.